# Flutter Ad Mob crashes my Android app when using real App Id

Tags: android, flutter, admob

I'm building a flutter app and trying to use Ad Mob.

I set my my App Id in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXX~YYYYYYYYYY"/>
```

My app works when using test Id but crashes when switching to my real App id.

Note that it crashes in both the simulator (`( 6370): This request is sent from a test device.`) and also my cellphone (but without saying much about why it crashes).

Note also the app does boot, but when scrolling to the place where the Ad would appear, it crashes. It does not crash if not scrolling down.

I'm using `google_mobile_ads: ^0.11.0`

any idea?